# When to use Else and when to use Elseif?

Tags: php

My question title basically says it all.. I'm seeing many examples with:

```
if (condition === comparison){

}elseif (condition === other_comparison){

}
```

and other examples with:

```
if (condition === comparison){

}else{

}
```

One looks to have many conditions, and the second looks to have only one? So when would I use `elseif` and when may I have `else`

Comment: *As appropriate*, obviously. `else` catches everything, `elseif` must fulfill another condition. *"Go to the store, if they have bread, buy bread, else if they're cheap, buy eggs"* vs. *"Go to the store, if they have bread, buy bread, else buy eggs."*

Comment: As you already indicated, Sophie, the `elseif` is for when you have multiple and exclusive (non-overlapping) conditions to check, whereas `else` is when you only have one condition to check.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is : if you have two variations of the result you have to use "else" and if you have more - "elseif"

Comment: I don't know if this makes any sense or if it's really "this simple".

Answer (score 2):

Else if is used for another condition. Else is for all other conditions. First one will try to check first condition, if not, check the other condition, if not, nothing happens. But the second one, do whatever is in else block in any case if first condition returns false.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (condition === comparison){
  //will only run if condition one is met
} elseif (condition === other_comparison){
 //will only run if condition two is met
}



if (condition === comparison){
  //will only run if condition is met
}else{
 //will run everytime if condition above is not met
 //this means no matter what something will run with this statement
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When to use it? Basically, when you have a variable which can be set with multiple different values. EG:

```
<?php 

    $Value = 1; // Could be set as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 or anything else. 

    if ($Value === 1){
        echo "Value Does Equal One";
    }elseif ($Value === 2){
        echo "Value Does Equal Two"; 
    }elseif ($Value === 3){
        echo "Value Does Equal Three"; 
    }
?>
```

And when to use a standard else statement, when you want to validate a variable as either one thing EG:

```
<?php 
    $Value = 2; 

    if ($Value === 2){
        echo "Value Matches Requirement"; 
    }else{
        echo "Value Does Not Match Requirement"; 
    }

?>
```

If Value on the above example does not equal to two, then the statement will enter the else.

Answer (score 1):

Else is best used when you want something to happen when the if or other else if criteria you have designated does not get met.

Leaving out an Else will allow you to only make changes if a criteria is met.

ElseIf is used to do the same as if, but have different results if the prior ifs are not met.

```
if (1==2)then
fail
elseif (1==1) then
YAY
end if
```